# Why the information I save in an event is being lost

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

good morning
I am trying to use Leaflet to paint an image and save the figures, I have created the following method to start the map:

```
initmap()
  {
    var url = 'http://kempe.net/images/newspaper-big.jpg';
    var bounds = [[-26.5,-25], [1021.5,1023]];
    var image = L.imageOverlay(url, bounds);
    var map = new L.Map('image-map', {layers: [image], crs: L.CRS.Simple, minZoom : -5});
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        position: 'topright',
        draw: {
            polyline: true,
            polygon: false,
            circle: false,
            marker: true
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems,
            remove: true
        }
    });
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
      var type = e.layerType,
              layer = e.layer;
      if (type === 'marker') {
          layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
      }

      drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
      var type = e.layerType
      var shape = layer.toGeoJSON()
      var shape_to_json = JSON.stringify(shape);
      this.currentMap = shape_to_json;
    });


    map.on(L.Draw.Event.EDITED, function (e) {
      var layers = e.layers;
      var countOfEditedLayers = 0;
      layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
          countOfEditedLayers++;
      });
    });
  }
```

As you can see there is an event definition for what to do when someone is drawing, (`map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e)` )
The point is that I log that method, with console.log to check what is saving in

```
this.currentMap = shape_to_json;
```

As you can see:

```
shape_to_json
installations-management.component.ts:120 {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[421.202413,315.527832],[421.202413,756.416626],[988.101415,756.416626],[988.101415,315.527832],[421.202413,315.527832]]]}}
```

Everything seems ok. But when I click on the save button, the data of this.currentMap is missing, and in no other point is being modifidied.So, am I saving it wrong or is modified somewhere because of the event?
Thank you all !

Comment: Not sure this is related to Angular - consider removing the Angular tag

Comment: The project is made in angular. Everything I posted is in the .ts file

Comment: Are you using [ngx-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) ? - if not consider using that because otherwise you might run into memory leaks and other issues